# TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am following the FULL STACK JAVASCRIPT DEVELOPMENT WITH MEAN by Adam Bretz & Colin J. Ihrig. When I got to chapter 8 I could not get past this error when trying to insert into an online mongo database. Do I need to use an older version of node? I've looked through stack exchange and have not been able to make it work following all of the suggested fixes... 
Here is my error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
    at insertEmployees (/Users/kikocarisse/Desktop/NODESITES/chapter8/index.js:100:17)
    at /Users/kikocarisse/Desktop/NODESITES/chapter8/index.js:195:5
    at /Users/kikocarisse/Desktop/NODESITES/chapter8/index.js:79:7
    at Function.<anonymous> (/Users/kikocarisse/Desktop/NODESITES/chapter8/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3369:16)
    at /Users/kikocarisse/Desktop/NODESITES/chapter8/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:1890:18
    at /Users/kikocarisse/Desktop/NODESITES/chapter8/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/async/internal/parallel.js:35:9
    at /Users/kikocarisse/Desktop/NODESITES/chapter8/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/async/node_modules/lodash/before.js:31:21
    at iteratorCallback (/Users/kikocarisse/Desktop/NODESITES/chapter8/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/async/eachOf.js:52:13)
    at /Users/kikocarisse/Desktop/NODESITES/chapter8/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/async/internal/onlyOnce.js:12:16
    at /Users/kikocarisse/Desktop/NODESITES/chapter8/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/async/internal/parallel.js:32:13
    at apply (/Users/kikocarisse/Desktop/NODESITES/chapter8/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/async/node_modules/lodash/_apply.js:15:25)
    at /Users/kikocarisse/Desktop/NODESITES/chapter8/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/async/node_modules/lodash/_overRest.js:32:12
    at model.callbackWrapper (/Users/kikocarisse/Desktop/NODESITES/chapter8/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:1865:11)
    at next_ (/Users/kikocarisse/Desktop/NODESITES/chapter8/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/hooks-fixed/hooks.js:89:34)
    at fnWrapper (/Users/kikocarisse/Desktop/NODESITES/chapter8/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/hooks-fixed/hooks.js:186:8)
    at /Users/kikocarisse/Desktop/NODESITES/chapter8/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3369:16
```

and here is my code:

```
"use strict";
var a = require('./a.js');
var b = new a(5);
var mongoose = require('./node_modules/mongoose');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('./node_modules/body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.route('/echo')
    .all((req,res)=>{
        let pars = (Object.keys(req.body).length > 0)?req.body:req.query;
        res.send(pars);
    });


var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var db = mongoose.connection;
var dbUrl = 'mongodb://*****:******@******:*****/****';

var TeamSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});
var Team = mongoose.model('Team', TeamSchema);

var EmployeeSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    first: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    last: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  team: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Team'
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
    default: 'images/user.png'
  },
  address: {
    lines: {
      type: [String]
    },
    postal: {
      type: String
    }
  }
});

var Employee = mongoose.model('Employee', EmployeeSchema);


db.on('error', function () {
  console.log('there was an error communicating with the database');
});

function insertTeams (callback) {
  Team.create([{
    name: 'Product Development'
  }, {
    name: 'Dev Ops'
  }, {
    name: 'Accounting'
  }], function (error, pd, devops, acct) {
    if (error) {
      return callback(error);
    } else {
      console.info('teams successfully added')
      callback(null, pd, devops, acct);
    }
  });
}

function insertEmployees (pd, devops, acct, callback) {
  Employee.create([{
    name: {
      first: 'John',
      last: 'Adams'
    },
    team: pd._id,
    address: {
      lines: ['2 Lincoln Memorial Cir NW'],
      postal: '20037'
    }
  }, {
    name: {
      first: 'Thomas',
      last: 'Jefferson'
    },
    team: devops._id,
    address: {
      lines: ['1600 Pennsylvania Avenue', 'White House'],
      postal: '20500'
    }
  }, {
    name: {
      first: 'James',
      last: 'Madison'
    },
    team: acct._id,
    address: {
      lines: ['2 15th St NW', 'PO Box 8675309'],
      postal: '20007'
    }
  }, {
    name: {
      first: 'James',
      last: 'Monroe'
    },
    team: acct._id,
    address: {
      lines: ['1850 West Basin Dr SW', 'Suite 210'],
      postal: '20242'
    }
  }], function (error, johnadams) {
    if (error) {
      return callback(error);
    } else {
      console.info('employees successfully added');
      callback(null, {
        team: pd,
        employee: johnadams
      });
    }
  })
}

function retrieveEmployee (data, callback) {
  Employee.findOne({
    _id: data.employee._id
  }).populate('team').exec(function (error, result) {
    if (error) {
      return callback (error);
    } else {
      console.log('*** Single Employee Result ***');
      console.dir(result);
      callback(null, data);
    }
  });
}

function retrieveEmployees (data, callback) {
  Employee.find({
    'name.first': /J/i
  }, function (error, results) {
    if (error) {
      return callback(error);
    } else {
      console.log('*** Multiple Employees Result ***')
      console.dir(results);
      callback(null, data);
    }
  });
}

function updateEmployee (first, last, data, callback) {
  console.log('*** Changing names ***');
  console.dir(data.employee);

  var employee = data.employee;
  employee.name.first = first;
  employee.name.last = last

  employee.save(function (error, result) {
    if (error) {
      return callback(error);
    } else {
      console.log('*** Changed name to Andrew Jackson ***');
      console.log(result);
      callback(null, data);
    }
  });
}

mongoose.connect(dbUrl, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('there was a problem connecting to the database!' + err);
  }
  console.log('connected!');

  insertTeams(function (err, pd, devops, acct) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err)
    }
    insertEmployees(pd, devops, acct, function (err, result) {

      retrieveEmployee(result, function (err, result) {

        retrieveEmployees(result, function (err, result) {

          updateEmployee('Andrew', 'Jackson', result, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
              console.error(err);
            } else {
              console.info('database activity complete')
            }

            db.close();
            process.exit();
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: For debugging in future; 1. view the error message's stack trace for files and line numbers; 2. navigate to the first file at that line; 3. log all if your identifiers immediately before it; 4. if something is unexpected, either add logic to catch it there or go back one level of your stack trace and repeat

Answer (score 1):

On line 100, the `devops` variable is `undefined` and that's why you're getting your error. See that on `insertTeams` function is where you will first get your devops value when creating the teams.

This is probably why there your create callback is like: `function (error, pd, devops, acct)` but seeing [Mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create), it pass an array as the second argument of create.

Try this:

```
function insertTeams (callback) {
  Team.create([{
    name: 'Product Development'
  }, {
    name: 'Dev Ops'
  }, {
    name: 'Accounting'
  }], function (error, teams) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return callback(error);
    } else {
      console.info('teams successfully added')
      callback(null, teams[0], teams[1], teams[2]);
    }
  });
}
```

Notice that now it gets an array and apss it's elements to the callback, also notice that I've added a log, if there is an error you are able to see where it happened.

Also, it'd help if you read the error logs and pointed what are the line contents where the error happens, see that we don't have the line numbers here and it makes it more difficult to find the errors.